# Refactoring for loop to Java 8 parallel stream

Tags: java, java-stream

```
public Double getTotal()
{
    Double totalAmount = 0D;
    long memberCount = 200;
    List<Fee> fees = feesMngr.all();
    for (FeeDto fee : fees)
    {
        if(fee.type.equals(FeeType.REGISTRATION))
        {
            Optional<Year> currentYear = this.getCurrentYear();
            if(currentYear.isPresent())
            {
                FeeDto addServiceCharge = feesMngr.getFeeByType(FeeType.SERVICE_FEE);
                totalAmount +=(addServiceCharge.getAmount() * memberCount);

            }
            if(feesMngr.getFeeByType(FeeType.LIBRARY_FEE) != null)
            {
                totalAmount += (200 * memberCount);
            }
        }
        else{
            totalAmount += (fee.getAmount() * memberCount);
        }
    }

    return totalAmount;
}
```

I have done something like the following but keep getting red lines; telling me "local variables referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively final". Still doesn't solve anything when i declare totalAmount final.

```
fees.parallelStream()
            .forEach(
                    (fee) -> {

                        if (fee.getType().equals(FeeType.REGISTRATION.name())) {

                            FeeDto addServiceCharge = feesMngr.getFeeByType(FeeType.SERVICE_FEE);

                            totalAmount += (fee.getAmount() * memberCount);

                        }
                        else {
                            totalAmount += (fee.getAmount() * memberCount);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: This is probably a great example of where using Java Streams would just make the code less readable. What's wrong with what you have now?

Comment: Nothing really. I learnt that to use Java stream makes processing faster.

Comment: And notwithstanding the above, this really isn't a "please convert my code for me" site, nor even a "please point me in the right direction" type site. Please check out the [help], the [tour] and the [ask] to see what this site is all about and how to best use it.

Comment: "to use Java stream makes processing faster" ???

Comment: Java Stream API purpose is to make code more readable and straight-forward, not to make code faster.

Comment: I am new to Java Stream API.

Comment: Instead of thinking about the Stream API, you should first fix the logic of the loop code. Why are you invoking `FeeDto addServiceCharge = feesMngr.getFeeByType(FeeType.SERVICE_FEE);` when you never use that value? Then, what’s the point of multiplying the never-changing `memberCount` to every summand? The result is not different to multiplying `memberCount` once to the final sum. The condition `feesMngr.getFeeByType(FeeType.LIBRARY_FEE) != null` is entirely independent from the object of the loop iteration. Why are you using `Double` instead of `double`?

Comment: It's been edited. Amount supposed to be gotten from addServiceCharge.
I prefer to use the Object than the primitive type.

Comment: Please anything yet on the code above?

Comment: variables that you use inside a lambda expression need to be final or in a way constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first step get amount value to factor for each conditions. After that you can do the whole computation:

```
        long memberCount = 200;
        return feesMngr.all().parallelStream().map(fee -> {
            if (fee.type.equals(FeeType.REGISTRATION)) {
                Optional<Year> currentYear = this.getCurrentYear();
                if (currentYear.isPresent()) {
                    return feesMngr.getFeeByType(FeeType.SERVICE_FEE).getAmount();
                }
                if (feesMngr.getFeeByType(FeeType.LIBRARY_FEE) != null) {
                    return 200D;
                }
                return 0D;
            } else {
                return fee.getAmount();
            }
        }).reduce(0D, (subAmount, factor) -> subAmount + (factor * memberCount));
```